# Can't subscribe to subscription forms in a website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form, subscription

I've tried using the plugins Contact Forms 7, Mailpoet, and other subscription forms for my website. Whenever a visitor tries to enter his email address into the form and when they click the subscribe button. Instead of subscribing, a pop up is showing up that says. "https://websitename.com is requesting your username and password. The site says: Restricted"

But, when I logged into the admin site and subscribe, I can subscribe just fine.

Can you let me know what's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the admin general setting "Membership" .You can find checkbox with "Anyone can register" option please active that one. Hope you will get the solution.

Comment: this is the url path https://websitename.com/wp-admin/options-general.php

Comment: Hello. Thank you. The checkbox is already active with the "New User Default Role" set to Subscriber. I want the visitors to be able to subscribe to the website successfully.

Comment: No, I said the option with "Anyone can register". is that also active ?

Comment: Yes. the option is active.

Comment: can i see your website ?